# Debug slow pptp connection in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pptpd

I've unstable connection when using a VPN (pptpd), obviously it works, but sometimes is slow or not responding for a few minutes.

Which log I should enable to debug the issue? 
e.g. due to pptpd? due to network timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without more information. The fact that it comes and goes sounds more like a network issue. An MTR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_%28software%29 is a very useful tool for debugging network issues. It combines both ping and traceroute tests to check latency and debug where the loss is.

Run it for 50 cycles when you are having problems, if you see packetloss or high ping, then it is probably your issue.